# Prompt a question similar to AskYesNo, but different value

Tags: r

I want to display a similar looking prompt question to askYesNo() but with different values to select.

I want to be able to select with a click, not through the console, a unique value. I am trying the following:

```
next_step = askYesNo("Choose a country", default = TRUE, 
                     prompts = getOption("askYesNo", gettext(c("Morocco", "Tunisia", "Cancel"))),)
```

But it still appears as

[image: askYesNo dialog]

Is there any way to change those values to the ones that I want?
Any other function that might help with this issue, a list display can be also useful, where I can select only one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, R only offers a few variations on the dialog you show, and none of them allow you to put arbitrary strings on the buttons.

However, you can use `menu()` for more flexibility.  For example,

```
menu(gettext(c("Morocco", "Tunisie", "Cancel")),
     graphics = TRUE,
     title = "Choose a country")
```

should display something useful for you.  I'm not on Windows, so I can't show you what it will look like for you.  On a Mac it looks like this:
[image: screenshot]